# javascript how to display 10 questions with onclick?

Tags: javascript, api, onclick

How can I get `button.onclick = () => {}` function to display 10 questions at once? Instead of creating only 1 question

I have (for 1 question display only)

```
button.onclick = () => {

createQuestion(characthersQuestion);
 }
```

I've got to change it to display 10 questions at once,
I'm assuming I got to use --for-- + numberofQuestions but I'm not sure.

The api i'm using --> `fetch('http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/api/characters')`

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise to do a better job of formatting your code using the editor and ask a clear, specific question in your title.

Comment: You should map through your API end point, and you can as much as you want. But also works with a for loop, although I believe that map is more efficient.

Comment: @Benji thanks, if i were to use for loop, what would be a good example that would work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure how to fetch another question, but the way seem to be like this:

```
button.onclick = () => {
    for (let i=0; i<10; i++){
        //I don't know the api, 
        //I am not sure if this will provide next question or the same as before
        characthersQuestion = fetch('http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/api/characters');
        createQuestion(characthersQuestion);
    }
}
```